# jquery menu slideshow error

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, settimeout

I am currently making a website that includes a menu navigation almost identical to the one found at [fotopunch.com](http://www.fotopunch.com) only instead of pointing down it points up. Anyways, I wrote the code using jquery/javascript for the menu and it works but there is a small error which also occurs at the fotopunch site. **When you move your cursor from one menu item to another and back repeatedly it messes up the display temporarily. Is there a way to fix this?** I will include part of my javascript file so you can see what I do for each menu item.

```
$("div#menu .reps").hover(function() {
    //if the current slide is not reps
    if(current_slide != "reps"){
    //move the arrow to the corresponding position for the reps slide 
        $(".arrow").animate({"left":"135px"});//move the arrow
        //(test which slide it is.)
        if(current_slide == "clients"){
            //fade out & hide the current slide
            $(".clients_display").fadeOut().hide();//hide the current slide
            //show the reps slide & fade in
            $(".reps_display").fadeIn().show();//show the slide
            //the current slide is the reps slide
            current_slide = "reps";
        }
        else if(current_slide == "services"){
            //fade out & hide the current slide
            $(".services_display").fadeOut().hide();//hide the current slide
            //show the reps slide & fade in
            $(".reps_display").fadeIn().show();//show the slide
            //the current slide is the reps slide
            current_slide = "reps";
        }
        else{
            //fade out & hide the current slide
            $(".training_display").fadeOut().hide();//hide the current slide
            //show the reps slide & fade in
            $(".reps_display").fadeIn().show();//show the slide
            //the current slide is the reps slide
            current_slide = "reps";
        }
    }
});
```

I do this for each menu item (there are 4). I think the problem is when it fades out and fades back in because if it tries to do too much at the same time it is displaying 2 of the menu divs at the same time. I tried to add a timeout but was unsuccessful. **What is the best way to fix this error?** It is small enough to not be a big priority but it would be nice to have it work better. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried http://api.jquery.com/stop/?

Comment: Cool. The stop function does fix it. But the arrow still lags when moving back and forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(current_slide == "clients"){

            $(".clients_display")stop(true, true).fadeOut().hide();

            $(".reps_display").stop(true, true).fadeIn().show();

            current_slide = "reps";

        } else if(current_slide == "services"){

            $(".services_display").stop(true, true).fadeOut().hide();

            $(".reps_display").stop(true, true).fadeIn().show();

            current_slide = "reps";
        } else{

            $(".training_display").stop(true, true).fadeOut().hide();//hide the current slide

            $(".reps_display").stop(true, true).fadeIn().show();//show the slide

         }
```